# How do you define your own datatype in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

Seeing as you can limit the parameters of functions to specific datatypes, it stands to reason that you might want to define your own datatype, yet I cannot see anything in the Rebol docs that suggests this as a feature of the language (unless I didn't look very well).

What I am expecting is the ability to do something like the following:

```
mytype!: make datatype! ... ; some spec here
```

Is this possible? The following does not fill me with much hope:

http://www.rebol.it/giesse/custom-types.r

From the link:

> Purpose: {
>           Allows the programmer to define custom REBOL datatypes
>       }

It is a rather lengthy piece of code. Not what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often suggested, as of today <strike>not implemented</strike> [available only as an experimental patch by Giulio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246899/211160).

Any useful custom datatype proposals usually come along with the desire to hook them in so they could effectively "overload" things like **+** or **append**.  There is an internal layer of abstraction called an **ACTION!** that in theory provides a place to put these hooks:

```
>> type? :append
== action!
```

Actions are a sort of "method call" (i.e. polymorphic) on the first argument, to which the ensuing parameters are passed.  There is currently no exposed way for users to create actions or create a new datatype that responds to them.

For Rebol 3, user-defined datatypes are proposed under the moniker "utype" -- have a look at ["What's known about UTYPE! in Rebol?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780398/whats-known-about-utype-in-rebol-3) for more.

In the [objects announcement for Red](http://www.red-lang.org/2014/12/050-objects-support.html), however, I noticed some fine print at the end:

> In order to help the Red compiler produce shorter and faster code, a new #alias compilation directive will be introduced. This directive will allow users to turn an object definition into a "virtual" type that can be used in type spec blocks. For example:
>
> ```
> #alias book!: object [
>     title: author: year: none
>     banner: does [form reduce [author "wrote" title "in" year]]
> ]
>
> display: func [b [book!]][
>     print b/banner
> ]
> ```
>
> This addition would not only permit finer-grained type checking for arguments, but also help the user better document their code.

Answer (score 5):

Tried an implementation of utypes in https://github.com/giuliolunati/rebol/tree/utype

As an example, I implemented [complex! utype](https://github.com/giuliolunati/rebol-lib/blob/master/complex.reb)

Basically, utypes are implemented as objects with special methods in dotted form: so, .add implements the + op etc.

For now you can overload all actions (but make), and some natives (math functions, comparison, form, mold, print, probe)